# How to md5 special characters - Thumbnail related

Tags: 18.04, thumbnails, md5sum

I have written a script to generate custom Thumbnail for my nikon raw files (.NEF). So far so good.
Now the thumbnail file name must be the md5 of the absolute path of the NEF image, as stated here [link](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/thumbnail-spec/thumbnail-spec-latest.html).

My generated md5 does not match with the one generated from the system, here are some tests with a .jpg file

```
path = 'file:///home/ricardo/Área de Trabalho/TempImgX/capa_site_01.jpg'

StrNoSpecial = 'file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fricardo%2F%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho%2FTempImgX%2Fcapa_site_01.jpg'

print(hashlib.md5((path).encode()).hexdigest())
print(hashlib.md5((StrNoSpecial).encode()).hexdigest())
```

Result:

```
f9aa4e24d9942a1b120ecc5b7af360f9
5dd1386290a8ea7642d5864c349c28d4
```

md5 of current working thumbnail on thumb. folder:

```
1f6cd39593b60e303d26856ffa471689
```

As you can see the hash are different. Is the special characters the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper encoding for the filename seems to be:

```
file:///home/ricardo/%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho/TempImgX/capa_site_01.jpg
```

That is: replace all blanks with `%20` and that `Á` with `%C3%81`. 
Don't replace the slashes `/` and the colon `:`. Then (in bash):

```
filename="file:///home/ricardo/%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho/TempImgX/capa_site_01.jpg";
echo -n "$filename" | md5sum
1f6cd39593b60e303d26856ffa471689  -
```

As [@Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) said in a comment,

> Not just {space} but `! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]` 
>   and any chars that are not in A-Z (like accents) 
>   [need replacement.]

Unfortunately you cannot apply this rule to the complete URI
`file:///home/ricardo/Área de Trabalho/TempImgX/capa_site_01.jpg` because that gives
`file%3A%2F%2F%2Fhome%2Fricardo%2F%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho%2FTempImgX%2Fcapa_site_01.jpg`
and that didn't work out.

Instead, the algorithm for that NEF/thumbnail tool seems to be working like so:

1. split the filename (like `/home/ricardo/Área de Trabalho/TempImgX/capa_site_01.jpg`) at `/` into parts
2. foreach such part replace all weird characters with their percent encoding
3. re-join the parts with `/`
4. prepend `file://`
5. apply `md5` to the resulting string.

Comment: Not just {space} but `! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]` and any chars that are not in A-Z (like accents) Sometimes a space needs to be a + too ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I added some pseudo code of what I think how the enconding should be applied. You cannot just replace _all_ `/` and `:` with their %XY. The OP already tried that to no avail. Instead, apply the encoding to the path components separately and then join them.

Comment: I have seen situations where I did had to do the / and : and where I was not allowed to do them.

Comment: You were right in the spot! Found a simple way to deal with the special characters: `from urllib.parse import quote` and then `StrNoSpecial = (quote(string, safe='/:'))` you can put all the characters you **DONT** want to change inside the `safe=''`